# OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=1607702 with wrong version (1), where current version is 4 in Spring Batch

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

I am facing an issue OptimisticLockingFailureException. I am not sure why batch is giving me this error. Let me share my code for better understanding,

**Reader**

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<Stage> stagingReader() throws Exception {
        JdbcPagingItemReader<Stage> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();

        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        //reader.setFetchSize(3);
        reader.setPageSize(10);
        reader.setSaveState(false);
        reader.setRowMapper(new StagingMapper());

        SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean factory = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        //factory.setDatabaseType("ORACLE");
        factory.setSelectClause("*");
        factory.setFromClause("from STAGE");
        
        factory.setSortKey("CID");
        PagingQueryProvider queryProvider = (PagingQueryProvider) factory.getObject();
        // call init to imitate spring context startup behaviour
        queryProvider.init(dataSource);

        reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider);

        return reader;
    }
```

**Step**

```
@Bean
    public Step processStagingDataStep() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("readStagingDataStep")
                .<Staging,Stage>chunk(10)
             
                .reader(stagingReader())
                .writer(compositeCustomerWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skip(DuplicateKeyException.class)
                .skipLimit(50)
                .exceptionHandler(importCustomBatchErrorHandler())
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }
```

I have 4 thread configuration with max limit of 4.

**My Writer**

```
@Component
//@StepScope
public class CompositeCustomerWriter implements ItemWriter<Staging> {

    @Synchronized
    //@Transactional
    @Override
    public synchronized void write(List<? extends Staging> items) throws Exception {
      1. Reading records from Main Stage and data insert into app tables (using Spring JPA PagingAndSortingRepository save method)
      2. Copying to BackUp Tables ( using Spring JPA PagingAndSortingRepository save method)
      3. Deleting records from Main Stage tables.(Using  jdbcTemplate.update here)

}
}
```

Above is my plain code, however when i do bulk processing i get error `OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=1607702 with wrong version (1), where current version is 4` and interesting in step-2 of writer when i copy into one of my tables i see strange message error like below

```
ERROR  [ImportPoolThread4 - BatchingBatch] HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: IOException while reading stream. Transaction should be rolled back.], SQL: insert into stg_ (name....other columns )values (?)
WARN   [ImportPoolThread4 - SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Error: 17266, SQLState: 99999
ERROR  [ImportPoolThread4 - SqlExceptionHelper] IOException while reading stream. Transaction should be rolled back.
```

Even in step-2 this tables sometime gets populated with null column(this column is foreign key).
I have also tried to control batch flush to hiberate with below

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=10
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction=true
```

But it did not work, i also tried to tried to SyncronizedItemreader in my reader but then my app doesnt pick it up. It tried to use this solution from [Github-PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1826#issuecomment-566286912) but i am not sure how to do flushing in Spring JPA with hibernate, as Itemwriter only has one implementation available method write.
Please assist to resolve these errors

`IOException while reading stream. Transaction should be rolled back.` (This could be root cause)

`OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=1607702 with wrong version (1), where current version is 4`

DB used is **oracle**.